# How to design a lab experiment showing differences between reversible and irreversible work?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry, teaching-lab

Some of my students keep asking for more information about reversible and irreversible work. I've been trying to think of a demonstration/experiment that might highlight the broad concepts but haven't gotten far. Does anyone know of or have any experience on such demonstrations or experiments?

Comment: As inspiration, see this simulated experiment [LearnChemE.com - simulations - thermodynamics - reversible-irreversible-expansion-compression-work](https://learncheme.com/simulations/thermodynamics/thermo-1/reversible-irreversible-expansion-compression-work/)

Comment: Make a list of processes that involve reversible work and a second list of processes that involve irreversible work.

Comment: Pull a weight on a rubber band, and let it snap back. Pull a weight on a rubber band until the band breaks. Where did that work go?

Comment: In a rapid irreversible compression, do you think that the gas satisfies the ideal gas law?

Comment: It probably does All the processes are the result of random molecular motion.

Comment: Each of them is a living example of a series of almost equilibrium reactions that extract work from a process. Compare eating a cookie, digesting it, getting energy to move etc., compared to just putting the cookie in a fire. The end products are the same: CO2 + H2O + energy. Processes are irreversible because they have the combination of negative deltaH and positive deltaS and cannot reach equilibrium. The trick is to control the entropy change.

Comment: @jimchmst

Thanks for your reviewing my post. Perhaps I wasn't clear in my original post, but by reversible and irreversible work I'm referring to expansion work (there's more on this in Atkin's Physical Chemistry). So, in essence I'd like a somewhat intuitive experiment or demonstration to show how the maximum expansion work for instance is the maximum work possible ...